# python2.7 - average of multiple opencv histograms

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, numpy, image-processing, histogram

I am using python2.7 opencv library to calculate histograms of some images, all of the exact same size (cv2.calchist)

i have a need to do 2 things:
 1. calculate the average of multiple images - multiple images who represent a similar object, and therefor i want to have a "representive" histogram of that object (if you have a better idea i am open to suggustions) for future comparisons.
 2. store the histogram data in my mongo db for future comparisons (cv2 correlation)

the only code i see rellevant for the question is my histogram_comparison code:

```
def histogram_comparison(real, fake):
images = [real, fake]
index = []
for image in images:
    image = image.decode('base64')
    image = np.fromstring(image, dtype=np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode(image, 1)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    hist = cv2.calcHist([image], [0, 1, 2], None, [32, 32, 32],
                        [0, 256, 0, 256, 0, 256])
    hist = cv2.normalize(hist).flatten()
    index.append(hist)
result_dist = cv2.compareHist(index[0], index[1], cv2.cv.CV_COMP_CORREL)
return round(result_dist, 5)
```

*taken from: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/14/3-ways-compare-histograms-using-opencv-python/*

i do realize that when using numpy's (or was it scipy?) histograms, there is an easy way to get the bins and average them, but then im not really sure how then to compare between histograms so i would rather stay with opencv

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since OpenCV (since 2.2) natively uses numpy arrays and since `len(images)` is constant, you can get avg between all your histograms and stores in mongo by simply:

```
h, b = np.histogram(images, bins=[0, 256])
db.histograms.insert({hist:(h/len(images)), bins:b })
```

I do not know if it's exactly what you want, but I hope it helps! See ya!

Comment: thank you! its working and i can convert a numpy array back to cv2 format in order to use its comparison